# Any difference between $\Delta$ and $\varDelta$?

Tags: notation

Notationally speaking, is there any difference between using $\Delta$ or $\varDelta$ ,or is it just user-preference, so to speak?

Comment: In good ol' days when we did our math with a pencil and a sheet of paper, there was no difference, I think. Some of us still do work this way. :)

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen $\varDelta$. If I'm not an outlier and $\varDelta$ really is rare, then I would say "look at the sources you have that use $\varDelta$ and see if anything is special about those contexts".

Comment: Late to the party here, but in my own (minimal) experience I've seen $\Delta$ used as a variable or the Laplacian and, confusingly, $\varDelta x$ used to denote $x_2 - x_1$